# Check if URL ends with specific string?

Tags: javascript, string

Now I have a URL which is

```
var url1 = 'www.test.com/test'
```

If I use

```
url1.indexOf('/test') !== -1  // will return true
```

What if I change the URL to

```
var url2 = 'www.test.com/test123'
url2.indexOf('/test') !== -1. // still return true
```

What I want to do is only this pattern `/test` can return true otherwise return false, for example `/test123` or `/test12312`

Comment: What do you expect from `www.test.com/test/1234` or `www.test.com/abc/test`. And that’s not really a URL btw.

Comment: `var hasTest = url1.split("/").slice(1).some( s => s == "test" );`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) method of String:

```js
let url1 = 'www.test.com/test',
    url2 = 'www.test.com/test123';

console.log(url1.endsWith('/test'));
console.log(url2.endsWith('/test'));
```

Answer (score 0):

guess you want this:

```js
var url1 = 'www.test.com/test';
var url2 = 'www.test.com/test123';
let reg=/\/test$/;
console.log(!!url1.match(reg));
console.log(!!url2.match(reg));
```

Comment: @Dreams,if it works,you can close the question by voting up or accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the URL contains `/test` **anywhere in the URL path after `origin`** then use `split`, `slice` and `some`

```
var fnHasValue = (url1, valueToCheck) => url1.split("/").slice(1).some( s => s === valueToCheck );
```

This should work for

```
fnHasValue("www.test.com/test", "test" ) //true
fnHasValue("www.test.com/test123", "test" ) //false
fnHasValue("www.test.com/abc/test", "test" ) //true
fnHasValue("www.test.com/test/abc", "test" ) //true
```