# how to check whether window.location.pathname ends with /search?

Tags: javascript, path, window.location, urlsearchparams

I am trying to track a page visit when someone lands on a search results page. Right now I have an isMatch function, and if it returns true, then it sends an event.

Is there a way to check against window.location.pathname, to basically check whether or not it **ends with** `/search?`? Here is an example URL when someone searches:

https://website.com/en_US/search?q=testin&search-button=&lang=en_US

Where "**testin**" is what the user inputted in the search bar.

Right now, I have:

```
isMatch: () => {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const paramValue = urlParams.get("q");
            return paramValue !== null && window.location.pathname === "/en_US/search";
```

However I want to check against if it ends with search so I don't have to include the locale (en_US) since we want to track this on multiple countries without having the change the code. Would something like `window.location.hash` work? I am not totally familiar with it.

Comment: Also see: [Check if URL ends with specific string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767662/check-if-url-ends-with-specific-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these two methods to handle it:

1. endWith()

```
    return window.location.pathname.endsWith("/search");
```

> Please Note that endsWith() is not supported in IE 11 (or earlier versions)

2. substring()

```
    let path= window.location.pathname;
    return path.substring(path.length-7) === "/search";
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, strings have the method `endsWith`, which works as you'd expect.

```js
window.location.pathname.endsWith("/search");
```